# Load and performance test - Kafka consumer

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, spring-kafka

How can i load test my spring boot kafka consumer? I have seen a lot of articles about load test apache kafka but i can't find load test for the consumer. For ex. I have written jmeter kafka producer test plan in jsr225 sample, sends events to kafka topic. My kafka spring boot consumer listen to this topic, consumes the event and start to process it. Jmeter is only shows me the report on the producer to the topic and that's it. Is there any way better to load test the spring boot kafka consumer application and get report on it? From the consume time to the end of the process?

Is there any way better to load test the spring boot kafka consumer application and get report on it? From the consume time to the end of the process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get either the timestamp of the processing start event or processing end even from the database or API.

The test plan can be organized as follows:

- [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) - to measure end-to-end processing time

  - [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to send the message to Kafka topic
  - [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) - to wait till the processing ends

    - [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler or [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to query the processing status

      - a PostProcessor to get the status from the response